# Python 3.6+ annotation of argument that could be of string or any class

Tags: python-3.x, annotations

```
from typing import Union, Callable, Any

def map_type(t) -> str:
    if isinstance(t, str):
        _type = t
    else:
        _type = t.__name__
    return {
        'float': 'float',
        'int': 'integer',
        'number': 'float',
        'bool': 'boolean',
        'date': 'date',
        'datetime': 'datetime',
        'list': 'list',
        'str': 'string'
    }.get(_type)
```

What to write for the annotation **t** then?

```
def map_type(t: Union[str, Any])->str: pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not any object, but any class? The type of classes is `type`

```
>>> type(int)
type
>>> type(str)
type
```

Thus you probably want a union of str and type,

```
def map_type(t: Union[str, type]) -> str:
    ...
```

The `Any` type just means "not type checked", which is useless in a union.